# Icon of App remains unchanged, whatever I try :(

Tags: facebook, icons

I have an app, and during development I used an ogg image to indentify the app.

Then, when the app was finished I gave it its own ogg image. I noticed that the app icon remained the old one.

Ok, cached, so used the FB linter. Linter showed correct image. Problems over I guessed.

Did a test post on my own time line, new image shows up. Hurray.

But, surprise surprise, if someone else posts the app, the old image appears. WFT?!

Ok, changed all images, of all my apps, put the all through the linter, the apps.facebook.com url, and the url of the app itself.

All show the correct image on the linter....

Now it must be ok, I thought.

But, suprise surprise a few days later someone posts a link to the app, et voila, the old image appears again..... $%&^#^$#@@@

What more can I do?

HELP! , thanks

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this is a caching problem. Try with a new anonymous chrome window (or empty your cache in another way) to see if that helps.

Comment: And BTW, the name of the ogg app icon has changed, now 3 times already :)

Comment: Then I guess you should be contacting facebook... They probably have a cache too.

Answer (score 0):

Ooops, programmers error....

The App icon changed all alright, but I forgot to adjust the image when a wallpost was made from the App....

Shame, red head., sorry.. :(

Forget it !

Comment: (but, I shows, that even if you use a link to an image that is deleted on your server, FB just takes the cached one, and gives no error or empty pic...)